# How can i validate the below dataframe by avoiding null, zero and none using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, fillna

Below are my two dataframes and i am trying to compare both of them. I just want to consider the first row from both the dataframes as same because the values are either none or na or blank.
how can i avoid them without any errors.

| Policy number | Limit Amount | Deductible | Terr_code | Reinsurance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | NaN | NaN | None | None |
| 1234 | 5 | 5 | Y | Y |
| 1234 | 20000 | 30000 | Y | Y |

Second dataframe:

| Policy number | Limit Amount | Deductible | Terr_code | Reinsurance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 0 | 0 |  |  |
| 1234 | 5 | 5 | Y | Y |
| 1234 | 20000 | 30000 | Y | Y |

Answer (score 0):

`NOTE:` Use `iloc[1:]` to remove the `1st row`:

If you need to test whether the df's are equal or not:

```
df1.iloc[1].equals(df2.iloc[1]) # prints True
```

Or if you wanna compare each and every value:

```
df1.iloc[1:].compare(df2.iloc[1:], keep_shape = True, keep_equal = True)
```

Comment: what if during runtime, i dont know that these duplicates are present in the first row.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert all these kinds of null values to the same value, for example, `NaN` before comparing the 2 dataframes.

To convert, we can define a dictionary for conversion/translation and then use `.replace` to convert both the dataframes.

Finally, we compare the 2 dataframes (after conversion) with [`.compare()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html)

```
import numpy as np

# define the null values conversion dict
same_dict = {'': np.nan, 0: np.nan, '0': np.nan, None: np.nan, 'None': np.nan, 'NaN': np.nan, 'nan': np.nan}

# apply the conversion to the 2 dataframes.  
df1r = df1.replace(same_dict, regex=True)
df2r = df2.replace(same_dict, regex=True)

# compare the 2 dataframes (after convesions)
# Either use compare option that shows differences only
df1r.compare(df2r)

# Or use compare option that keeps all similarities and differences for detailed checking:

df1r.compare(df2r, keep_shape=True, keep_equal=True)
```

Here, we define the dict for conversion to convert all the following kinds of null values.  You are free to add or remove entries:

```
''        empty string
0         zero (numeric type)
'0'       zero (character type) 
None      None
'None'    String of None
'NaN'     String of NaN
'nan'     String of nan (appears when converting NaN to string)
```

**Result:**

```
df1r.compare(df2r)

#  Nothing shown as the 2 dataframes have identical elements


df1r.compare(df2r, keep_shape=True, keep_equal=True)

  Policy number       Limit Amount          Deductible          Terr_code       Reinsurance      
           self other         self    other       self    other      self other        self other
0          1234  1234          NaN      NaN        NaN      NaN       NaN   NaN         NaN   NaN
1          1234  1234          5.0      5.0        5.0      5.0         Y     Y           Y     Y
2          1234  1234      20000.0  20000.0    30000.0  30000.0         Y     Y           Y     Y
```